# Ext js accordins doesnot load on page load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have ext-js accordions in my westpanel and it loads fine after i click on the page.. but I want it to be loaded on page load..

can anyone suggest a solution

Comment: what did you mean by "load on click page"? and what addaccordians() do??

Comment: addaccordians():- is a JS function which will create accordians and treepanel

Comment: and "load on click page"  means it wil not load on page load but if i click on two or three times on browser automatically it will be loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you forget to add the "center" region in viewport? In border layout , a center region is mandatory. Please use firebug while testing.

And, yes, what that addaccordians() function does? If you are adding a component to any other component, do use doLayout() method.

Comment: addaccordians() is a java script function which will create accordians and treepanel structure.

Comment: Did you test in firebug? Are you getting any error? Did you actually add the center region in your code?